# Water drop animation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I have a project that requires a couple of animations, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.  These are:

1) a single drop of water falling from an eye dropper of sorts.

2) a drop on a surface, with a kind of top-down view, that moves around with changes in the accelerometer.

I am fairly well-versed in Core Animation.  Any high-level ideas I could begin to explore?

Comment: I'm only asking here because I have never done this type of thing.  I am not trying to get people to do work for me, I was just wondering if I could be pointed in the right direction, at a very high level.  But, noted.  I'll be more aware of asking questions like these in the future.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you experiment with animating the path of a CAShapeLayer. For the first example you could have your drop grow in size, get longer before it leaves the end of the dropper. You could of course get the same effect with an image and clever use of transforms (scaling in one direction to make it thinner etc). The second example would probably best be done with a shape layer since if the drop should have an irregular shape. If it is just a circle then you can do it in other ways. The real question is how you want the drop to look and behave. Doing the drawing is not the hard part.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the best course of action.  I've played a bit with shape layers in the past, actually...just at a very basic level.  Will read the docs.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure if that's similar thing, but I need something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928536/uiview-surface-custom-transformation-animation-like-a-water-drop-effect. Were you lucky with the question? Could you share any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might find this recent post on Cocoanetics useful: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/lets-bounce/

It discusses animating a bounce, rather than a drop, but I'm sure the methods discussed therein would also apply to your case.