# UIView surface custom transformation/animation (like 'a water drop effect')

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, transformation

What is the way to implement **custom transformation** (+ animation) on a **view surface** (similar to the images attached) (***not*** just the ***view bounds***).

The question is mainly in **what is the general way** to do that (not exactly the 'water drop effect', but any examples would be appreciated for sure). I guess, that's some 'algorythmic' transformation of the layer layout 'grid', but not sure which way to 'dig' that in.

(Another thought is that might be achieved with using some frameworks, however, I would still need to understand the core logic).

**UPDATE:**

Pretty good resource for animations lovers recently been found from one of the answers: [iPhone Development Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIViewAnimationState).

[image: transformation sample 1]
[image: transformation sample 2]

Answer (score 6):

Read this excellent blog post by Bartosz Ciechanowski:

http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/05/14/mesh-transforms/

To wrap it up: Apple does this with private API around a class called 'CAMeshTransform'.

The author proposes an self-written substitute:

https://github.com/Ciechan/BCMeshTransformView

It's pretty amazing actually!

Comment: Actually, it happened that I need some time for that stuff at the moment. But sounds amazingly, actually! Thank you for the answer anyway. Will have a look a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
- (void)drawWaterRippleAnimation {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.75];
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];

    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
    animation.endProgress=1;
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

Credits goes to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5973530/1371949).

Comment: Ha ha! Four year and bah! Good answer! )
There is a good link on the page you are referring: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIViewAnimationState. Will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Will be highly appreacite if you could tick this as answer :D

Comment: Frankly speaking, not working with iOS for two years already. )
So, just cannot test it at the moment...